# ng build not working after I installed the material color picker

Tags: angular, ng-build

This error message came after I installed the material color picker and tried to start the ng build:

> WARNING in Entry point '@angular/cdk/collections' contains deep imports into 
>   'C:/Users/vargaadam/code/LICON/angular/node_modules/mat-color-picker/node_modules/rxjs/Subject', 
>   'C:/Users/vargaadam/code/LICON/angular/node_modules/mat-color-picker/node_modules/rxjs/Observable'. This 
>   is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.

I tried to remove all node_modules and reinstall again, but this solution did not help.
What solution can I help to keep the ng build error free?

Comment: That's a warning not an error!

Comment: but the interface does not come in because of the message

Comment: any error on browser console?

Comment: The console is empty.